# AngularJS : How to access Parent's Named Controller inside Javascript files and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, requirejs, named

I have been working with named controllers lately and its way better than using the traditional $scope variables. Inside the DOM, it becomes very easy to access the parent controller's attributes and function. An example is given below.

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl as parent">
    <div ng-controller="childCtrl as child">
        Parent age is {{ parent.age }}
        Child age is {{ child.age }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I was wondering how to use the same named controller inside the javascript file for angular. Somewhat like mentioned below.

```
angular.controller('childCtrl',function(...) {
    var vm = this;
    this.age = 24;
    console.log(parent.age);
});
```

I know that the parent must be injected before using it. In my project I am making use of RequireJS along with UI Router so it completely avoids the `angular.controller` and such other constructs. Can anyone give me a solution in Plain vanilla Angular or with the help of RequireJS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My goto solution would be to use the $scope variable to access the parents scope.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  this.name = 'from parent';
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.name = $scope.parent.name;
});
```

[Here is a plunker with the full example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0hM3UlDWwHhpp5SGqxNg?p=preview)

To use a better design when sharing data between controllers [Angular services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) are the better solution.
If you change the DOM layout and move a child ctrl then the app might break. By using services, the controllers are independent of the DOM layout.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It was helpful :)